# CMake output artifact as a gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle, jar, cmake

I have an Android Studio project with CMake. CMake script produces *.so library and "*.jar" files. I need to set CMake output artifact "*.jar" as dependency for the gradle script.

I try to add this line in to the gradle script:
`api files(project.rootDir.toString() + '/build/mylib.jar')`, but "Android Studio" complains that file should exist.

Is it possible to produce "*.jar" artifact with CMake and set it as dependency for gradle script in Android Studio?